# $post->ID not working

Tags: posts

I have the following code and while get_the_ID() works, $post->ID does not, why?

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'custompost',
    ) );

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo $post->ID;
    endwhile;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your WP_Query loop is incomplete. Your not checking if any posts were actually found before looping, nor are you presenting a message to show none were found, nor are you cleaning up afterwards. You're also using the 'other' syntax that breaks brace matching in IDEs, making your life harder.

Try adding `global $post;` like this:

```
global $post;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'custompost'
) );

if($the_query->have_posts()){
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo $post->ID;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}else {
    echo 'no posts found';
}
```

When writing queries it's important to be consistent and to get things right. So I recommend reading these slides by Andrew Nacin, a WordPress Core developer at Auttomatic:

http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012

This will tell you where each type of query is appropriate, how they should be used, and why.

In the code above, I added an if statement to check if any posts were returned, and I added wp_reset_postdata which would allow you to continue using the main query by cleaning up after the custom loop.

Comment: Thanks the global did the trick then, how does that work? And what does wp_reset_postdata() do exactly? Is it always needed?

Comment: I guess `$post` was just out of scope, as for `wp_reset_postdata()`, when you start running through your loop, the $post variable is modified, so wp_reset_postdata() is like an undo on that, so you can use multiple loops within your main query without breaking it.

Comment: You should look at these slides: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012 It's an incredibly useful set of slides on making queries by Nacin one of the core devs, it explains everything

Comment: I agree with everything except the "other" syntax comment. Most of the time we're going to be outputting html inside of the while loop, so the "other" syntax is usually more appropriate. Link to the alternative syntax documentation incase anyone is interested - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: If you disagree I suggest you write a blog post or ask a new question, but you'll need something better than it being 'more appropriate', claims need to be backed up

Answer (score 0):

The trick, as identified by Tom Nowell, is to add a reference to `global $post`.

When you run `the_query->the_post()`, WordPress loads the first result of the query into a global `$post` object.  This is how it sets things up for all of the regular template tags:

- `the_title()`
- `the_content()`
- `the_excerpt`()
- etc ...

You see that we don't pass anything *in* to these functions. We just call them.  Each of these functions will internally reference the global `$post` object in order to parse, prepare, and print the desired output.

Inside your loop, you call `the_post()` just fine to populate the data, but you don't have a *reference* to the data itself within the scope of your loop.  If you wanted to avoid referencing the global `$post` object, you could instead use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).

Like the other template tags I've referenced above, `get_the_ID()` summons data from the global `$post` object internally, so you don't have to do it yourself.

But if you *do* want to do this yourself, just add a global reference before you try to use `$post`:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'custompost',
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    global $post;  // Add this line and you're golden
    echo $post->ID;
endwhile;
```

### What is `wp_reset_postdata()`?

If you're building multiple loops, (i.e. you have a large post loop, but call some secondary loop inside of it), you can call `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset things.

Basically, `the_post()` will set the global `$post` object to have the data for the requested query.  `the_query->the_post()` will overwrite `$post` with data from `the_query`.  `wp_reset_postdata()` will reset `$post` to the original query.

So if you're using nested or multiple loops, `wp_reset_postdata()` is a way to get back to the loop and `$post` object you had available before you called your secondary `the_query->the_post()`.