# PHP: Why does my code work in index.php but not a widget?

Tags: php, plugin-development, widgets, child-pages, wp-list-pages

I have been working for 7 days straight to perfect code that generates a submenu on pages that have children. Since it was so complex I figured I'd write it in my index.php file and then migrate it to a widget plugin once I got it working. It now works flawlessly but when I move it over to my plugin it doesn't identify the page levels (parent/child/grandchild) correctly. I have tested the plugin to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong with the setup. It works as it should.

Here is the code that works correctly in my index.php. I try pulling in all the code within my `<aside>` tags to the plugin (excluding the jquery) and I get first + second level pages where I should have second level, and first level pages where I should have third level:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
              <div class="submenu">
                    <?php
                    if(count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 1 ) {
                        echo '<ul>';

                        $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'page',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
                        );
                        $query = new WP_Query($args);
                        while ($query->have_posts()) {
                            $query->the_post();

                        $child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

                             if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>

                                <li class="has-children"><a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                                <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1' );
                                if ( $children) : ?>
                                    <ul class="children collapse" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?> ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
                                        <?php echo $children; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php else : ?>

                                <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                            <?php endif; 
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                    elseif (count(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) == 2 ) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'page',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'post_parent' => get_post( $post->post_parent )->post_parent,
                                'depth' => 1,
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query($args);
                            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                            $query->the_post();

                            $child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

                            if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
                                <li class="has-children"><a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                                <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1' );
                                if ( $children) : ?>
                                    <ul class="children collapse" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?> ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
                                        <?php echo $children; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </li>

                            <?php else : ?>

                            <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                            <?php endif; 
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                    elseif (get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID) ) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'page',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                'depth' => 1,
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query($args);
                            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                            $query->the_post();

                            $child = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);

                            if( count( $child ) != 0 ) : ?>
                                <li class="has-children"><a href="#<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"><?php the_title(); ?><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                            <?php $children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0&depth=1' );
                                if ( $children) : ?>
                                    <ul class="children collapse" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                    <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Overview</a></li>
                                        <?php echo $children; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </li>

                            <?php else : ?>

                            <li <?php if(is_page($post->ID )) {?> class="current_page_item" <?php }?>><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                            <?php endif; 
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {

  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.glyphicon', this)
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
  });
});

if ( $('.children li').hasClass('current_page_item') ) {
    $('.list-group-item .glyphicon', this)
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right')
      .toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $('.children', this)
      .addClass('in');

};

});
</script>     

              </div>
            </aside>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. Perhaps rephrasing will help. You should move `<aside>` to a sidebar instead of putting it on `index.php` also this is not how you use jQuery in WP.

Comment: Yes, I will move my jquery once I get the submenu out of the index file. I was just trying to develop everything where it was easy to get to. Same goes for the aside. 

When I move my code over to the widget it doesn't identify page IDs the same way it did in the index file. At least that's what I think is happening. For instance, when I say wp_list_pages should be a child of post_parent it's pulling in "home"; "about"; "contact us" instead of all the children of "about". But it does pull in all the child pages if the code is in my index.php file.

Comment: Okay, Did you try to print out the page id? It could be the page id is not set or something? Note that you should save the `$post->ID` into a variable for example `$current_page_id = $post->ID` just before the loop. While you are inside the loop the `$post` variable is changed to. `$post->ID` outside of the loop and `$post->ID` inside the loop is not the same.

Comment: So while trying to implement your comment I came across this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62810/post-id-not-working. I added `global $post;` to the top and it works perfectly now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `global $post;` to the top.

I came across this solution while working with user [sisir](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3094/sisir) on troubleshooting. While trying to perform the exercises he suggested I came across this post: [$post->ID not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62810/post-id-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you asked for, but could you try Running it in [PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/) and check if it works? If it does, there is probable something wrong with your widget generation code. If it does not, try adding that to sidebar.php and not index.php and check the results again.

Comment: So it produces the same wacky results in the PHP Code Widget as it does in my custom widget but does work perfectly in sidebar.php.